# Cross validation error

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to estimate the accuracy of Naive Bayes classification of the nltk movie reviews corpus.

```
from nltk.corpus import movie_reviews
import random
import nltk
from sklearn import cross_validation
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import string
from nltk.classify import apply_features

def document_features(document):
    document_words = set(document)
    features = {}
    for word in unigrams:
        features['contains({})'.format(word)] = (word in document_words)
    return features

documents = [(list(movie_reviews.words(fileid)), category)
             for category in movie_reviews.categories()
             for fileid in movie_reviews.fileids(category)]
random.shuffle(documents)
stop = stopwords.words('english')
all_words = nltk.FreqDist(w.lower() for w in movie_reviews.words() if w.lower() not in stop and w.lower() not in string.punctuation)
unigrams = list(all_words)[:200]
featuresets = [(document_features(d), c) for (d,c) in documents]
```

I am trying to perform a 10-fold cross-validation, and I have taken an example from sklearn.

```
training_set = nltk.classify.apply_features(featuresets, documents)
cv = cross_validation.KFold(len(training_set), n_folds=10, shuffle=True, random_state=None)

for traincv, testcv in cv:
    classifier = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(training_set[traincv[0]:traincv[len(traincv)-1]])
    result = nltk.classify.util.accuracy(classifier, training_set[testcv[0]:testcv[len(testcv)-1]])
    print 'Accuracy:', result
```

But I get an error in the line

```
classifier = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(training_set[traincv[0]:traincv[len(traincv)-1]])
```

'list' object is not callable

Any ideas what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual error lies in this line:

```
training_set = nltk.classify.apply_features(featuresets, documents)
```

`featuresets` is the list Python is complaining about.

From the documentation of `nltk.classify.apply_features`:

> **apply_features(feature_func, toks, labeled=None)**
>
> Use the `LazyMap` class to construct a lazy list-like
>   object that is analogous to `map(feature_func, toks)`.  In
>   particular, if `labeled=False`, then the returned list-like
>   object's values are equal to:
>
> ```
> [feature_func(tok) for tok in toks]
> ```
>
> If `labeled=True`, then the returned list-like object's values
>   are equal to:
>
> ```
> [(feature_func(tok), label) for (tok, label) in toks]
> ```

Behaving in a similar way to `map`, this function expects a *function* (feature extractor) as first argument which will be applied to every element (document) of the list which is passed as second argument. It returns a `LazyMap` which applies the function on demand to save memory.

But you have passed a list of feature sets to `apply_features` instead of a feature extractor function. Thus, there are two possible solutions to make things work like you want them to:

1. Discard `training_set` and use `featuresets` instead.
2. Discard `featuresets` and use `training_set = nltk.classify.apply_features(document_features, documents, True)` (note the third parameter).

I recommend the second option since it does not construct the list of features of all documents in-memory.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer! It has worked if I remove `training_set = nltk.classify.apply_features(featuresets, documents)` and say `training_set = featuresets`. Will I like this use all the document features and not only the 200 unigrams? With `training_set = nltk.classify.apply_features(featuresets, documents, True)` I get the same error.

Comment: I'm sorry: The second way had to be: `training_set = nltk.classify.apply_features(document_features, documents, True)` (use the feature extractor function instead of the actual result). However, you will always use the top 200 unigrams, since you have defined them to be your boolean features. If you would use all words appearing in any document, the feature space would be extremely large.